# Delete property from scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-templates

I have a scope variable `$scope.object = { prop: 12345 }` whose properties I delete with setting them to `undefined`.

```
<button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="object.prop = undefined"/>
```

Is there a possibility to delete a properties from within a template and without an additional function in the controller instead of setting their values to `undefined`?

Comment: Do you want to delete specific property from the object or all of them?

Comment: @AmirAl: A specific property anywhere inside of the object. For example at path "object.prop.foo[2].bar".

Comment: @AmirAl: It's not a duplicate since we are talking about AngularJS template code not Javascript Code.

Comment: You are right, it's not duplicate.

Answer (score 12):

use codes below to delete a property from a object

In HTML

```
<button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="deleteProperty()" />
```

In Controller

```
$scope.deleteProperty = function() {
    delete $scope.object.prop;
}
```

Comment: That is not convenient way to do it because if you want to delete other properties in the object you can't do with such method. According to your method you can delete only prop named property in the object.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question since this involves controller functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... I.e. that you can change the value of the variable ... Maybe it will be a help for you

try this:

```
 <button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="object.prop = 'undefined'"/>
```

or you can clear the value...

```
 <button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="object.prop = ''"/>
```

also you can set the value to null

```
 <button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="object.prop = null"/>
```

Comment: That would change the property to a `string` with the value `"undefined"` or `""`. So this does not delete anything.

Comment: also you can set the value to null `<button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="object.prop = null"/>`

Comment: It's still existing then.

Comment: @Ted, are you able to use Underscore.js library?

Comment: @Amir: Only AngularJS. :'(

Comment: @Ted I have added an answer, but it requires Underscore.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way that you can delete any property name from the object of scope. This method require using Underscore.js library.

**index.html**

```
//Underscore.js must be imported
<script src="path/to/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>

//Replace prop with any property name
<button ng-click="removeMyProperty(object, 'prop')">Test</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.object = {"prop": "test", "anotherProp" : 10};
$scope.removeMyProperty = function(variable, propName){
    var keys = _.keys(variable);
    _.each(keys, function(data){
        if(data === propName){
            $scope.object = _.omit(variable, propName);
        }
        else {
            console.log("No such property name in array!");
        }
    });
};
```

This works only when you use Underscore.js library and thus you must add it to your project classpath and import underscore.js file in index.html

If you are not familiar with Underscore, please go here [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If the object is always at a point that you know what properties it would have besides the one you are deleting you could try something like:

```
<button ng-show="object.prop" ng-click="object = {otherProp1: object.otherProp1, otherPropN: object.otherPropN}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do that. I tried using "delete" operator, something like `ng-click="delete object.prop"`. But it turns out that AngularJS expressions are limited and this gives me a $parse error while compiling the template, so you would have to write that in controller in order to completely delete it, unfortunately.

But if you want to avoid the controller at all means, setting the property to undefined might be a better idea, read the answer by Dan in this question: [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)